# sax parser returns empty string from xml

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

i'm trying to parse xml with stax.
after i'm going to this line in xml -

```
<temperature>38</temperature>
```

i am get a empty  string value. Why this happens ? What can i do to solve this ?
 my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flowers>
    <flower name="rose">
        <soil>podzolic</soil>   
        <visualParameters>
            <stemColor>Green</stemColor>
            <leafColor>Red</leafColor>
            <averageSize>50</averageSize>
        </visualParameters>
        <growingTips>
            <temperature>38</temperature>
            <watering>1200</watering>
            <value>photophilous</value>
        </growingTips>
    <multiplying>bySeeds</multiplying>
    <origin>Belarus</origin>
        <description>Classic Choice</description>
    </flower>
</flowers>
```

my code :

```
  List<Flower> getFlowerList() {
        return flowerList;
    }
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException { 
        switch (qName) {
            case "flowers":
                flowerList = new ArrayList<Flower>();
                break;
            case "flower":
                flower = new Flower();
                flower.setName(attrs.getValue("name"));
                break;
            case "visualParameters":
                visual = new VisualParameters();
                break;
            case "GrowingTips":
                tips = new GrowingTips();
                break;
        }

    }
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException { 
        switch (qName) {
            case "flower":
                flowerList.add(flower);
                break;
            case "soilType":
                soil = new SoilType();
                soil.setValue(SoilName.fromValue(content));
                break;
            case "origin":
                flower = new Flower();
                flower.setOrigin(content);
              break;
            case "averageSize":
                  visual.setAverageSize(Integer.valueOf(content));
              flower.setParameters(visual);
               break;
            case "leafColor":
                visual.setLeafColor(content);
                flower.setParameters(visual);
                break;
            case "temperature":
             //in this line content = ""
                tips.setTemperature(Integer.valueOf(content));

                break;
            case "stemColor":
                visual.setStemColor(content);
                flower.setParameters(visual);
                break;
            case "watering":
                tips.setWatering(Integer.valueOf(content));
                break;
            case "lightingType":
                tips.setValue(LightingName.fromValue(content));
                break;
            case "multiplying":
                multiplyingType = new MultiplyingType();
                multiplyingType.setValue(MultiplyingName.fromValue(content));
                break;
            case "description":
                flower.setDescription(content);
                break;
        }

    }
 public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
    }
```

and the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tasks.five.parser.SAXHandler.endElement(SAXHandler.java:75)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at tasks.five.parser.SAXParserClass.SAXParser(SAXParserClass.java:22)
    at tasks.five.command.SAXParserCommand.execute(SAXParserCommand.java:13)
    at tasks.five.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:21)
    at tasks.five.runner.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case code in `startElement()` is searching for `"GrowingTips"` instead of `"growingTips"`, and case statements are case sensitive. So in the `endElement()` code, when you try to set the temperature, `tips` is null, and causes `NullPointerException` to be thrown.

Comment: Thank you. why I do not notice it. I think the problem is more global than that;)

Answer (score 2):

Your `characters()` method is wrong:

```
content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
```

Text data can be divided up into chunks any way the parser chooses, and delivered in multiple calls of `characters()`. You need to append to the value of `content`, not to overwrite it each time.

Comment: thank you for advice. but why it is wrong ? Why this better ? i need the content value only once, before i set the setter of the class. after that i don't need this data, and in this case i am overwrite value to next, that i need.

Comment: If the text node "photophilous" is split up by the parser into three sections "phot", "ophi", and "lous", then your current code will only capture the last segment and will assume that the value was "lous". This doesn't happen often, so it is a particularly nasty bug in your code, because it may well not show up in most of your tests.